# how to change Aframe Gizmo for Translation the style?

Tags: three.js, aframe, archilogic, 3d.io

I want change aframe Gizmo for the translate and rotation style of the below images.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohuf6.png)

How to change TransformControls.js for https://github.com/aframevr/aframe-inspector/tree/master/src/lib/vendor/threejs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can fork the inspector repo, make the changes you want, host it somewhere and set the url on the inspector component:

```
<a-scene inspector=“url: http://yoururl”><a-scene>
```